# Windows Media Center history

Tags: windows-media-center, htpc

I would like  to know the means that WMC can determine if it had already downloaded a movie or series episode so it doesn't record it again.  I encode unprotected videos aster recording due to space limitations but I'm not sure I'd I need to do anything special In order for WMC to still respect the encoded file as a specific show.  Is it strictly filename based?  Or metadata?  Is there documentation to this?  Can the encoded files be moved to media folders that WMC is aware of instead of the recorded TV folder?